# How to select 2 Form as parameters in a form in c#

Tags: c#

I have a `method` in a `class` that take 2 `parameters` like this:

```
public static void ShowSelectedFeeds(Form1 frm, Form2 frm2)
{  
  //Some code here.
}
```

but I don't know how to recall it in a form,

I recall `methods` whit 1 `parameters` like this:
for example the `Selectoin_method` is in DbCon `Class` and take 1 parameter `Form1 frm`

in `Form1_Load`:

```
DbCon.Selection_method(this)
```

but when it's come to a `method` that take 2 `parameters` and I want to recall it in a `Fome2_Load` I use this code but it doesn't work(Shows NO exception or error, nothing happen at all)

```
private void AddFeedsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    DBConnection.ShowSelectedFeeds(frm, this);
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: You probably want to pass a form instance that is actually shown, instead of making a new form that is never displayed.

Comment: You should name your forms.

Comment: How do you create the `Form2`?

Comment: @Valentin with add item in solution exporer!

Comment: @SaraniO Can you show the counstuctor of `Form2`?

Comment: @Valentin you mean this?
    `namespace Ration_1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }`

Comment: @SaraniO What is the relationship between `Form1` and `Form2`? Which form does open first?

Comment: @Valentin `Form1` open First and `Form2` open with a `button` in `Form1`

Comment: @SaraniO Can you provide the code where you create the `Form2`. Something like `Form2 f = new Form2(); f.Show();`

Comment: this is it : `private void AddFeedbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            frm2.ShowDialog();
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a`Form1` variable inside `Form2` and set it in the constructor of `Form2`. Like:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form 
{ 
    Form1 form1;
    public Form2(Form1 form) 
    {  
        InitializeComponent(); 
        form1 = form; 
    }
}
```

So when you create a `Form2` you should pass a `Form1` instance in the constructor.

```
private void AddFeedbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);// <--- Form1 instance 
     frm2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen; 
     frm2.ShowDialog(); 
}
```

And then you can pass the `form1` variable in the method.

```
private void AddFeedsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DBConnection.ShowSelectedFeeds(form1, this);
}
```

Comment: tanks a lot, It work perfect.
what about Form3 or Form4? add them Just like this?

Comment: @SaraniO well, it depends, if they are all nested - this way is OK, otherwise you probably need to think about proper architecture.